# Is there a way to expand and filter using a substring in the Sharepoint API?

Tags: javascript, rest

I'd like to expand files and filter using a substring like so:

Is it possible?

```
/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('production_library')/files?$expand&?$filter=substringof(%27https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/Production_Library/Communication%20Management%27,url)%20eq%20true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported.

The following query returns files from `Documents` library located under `Guides` folder  with associated list items those names contains `SharePoint` keyword:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('documents/guides')/files?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$filter=substringof('SharePoint',Name)
```